# Visual Studio 2019 Menu items not responding

Tags: visual-studio

I recently got a new machine and installed Visual Studio 2019 Community on it. I'm editing some C# and trying to format the code (Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document) and nothing happens. I'm also getting errors that say things like 'Invalid Expression term 'string'' on a blank line. If I look at the error window it says there are no errors.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the solution and recreated it and now it works fine.